# Sci-Fi novel from 70s? Rich men adopt boys as sole heir; transfer minds into them. Howard Hughes involved. Reporters find out. “Children” in title?

Tags: story-identification, mind-uploading

Characters:

Romanello, Bauer, Peterson, Male newspaper columnist (Chandler?), Female TV news anchor.

Author Robinson/Roberts/Richardson or some variant

Secret clinic in Switzerland

Comment: Welcome! Have a look at our [How to ask a good story-id question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) guide to see if there is anything else you can remember to help our user find what you are looking for. It does sound like a fun story!

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: This clearly isn't what you were asking for, but Greg Egan's short story [_The Extra_](http://eidolon.net/?story=The%20Extra) has a similar theme and a horrifying (and very Eganesque) outcome.  You might enjoy it. It's available online for free.

Answer (score 18):

*[The Children](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2979501-the-children)* by Charles Robertson

[image: Front cover of The Children]

> THE CHILDREN
>
> You might meet them anywhere. In the subway. On a plane. In your bedroom. So innocent in their blue schoolboy blazers. So angelic with their bright faces.
>
> THE CHILDREN
>
> Do not be deceived. They are the sons of wealth and power. And behind their shining eyes lurk cold, murderous hearts.
>
> THE CHILDREN
>
> They are the weapons in a secret army. They might be anywhere from New York to Houston to Switzerland. They are waiting. For you.
>
> THE CHILDREN
>
> Mark Chandler, tough reporter. Shelley James, top TV anchorwoman. Media stars, competitors, lovers. They have stumbled on the hottest, most dangerous story of this year or any year. They are the only two people on earth who can stop...
>
> THE CHILDREN

Howard Hughes gets mentioned in [this review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1993271152?book_show_action=true):

> An 11 year old has his brain written over with the brainwaves of Howard Hughes and now he walks around Manhattan in his private school uniform shooting people who might reveal his dark secret in the face.

Found with a search for `science fiction novel "howard hughes" brain transplant`, which turned up [this article](https://www.tor.com/2017/05/05/nazi-super-babies-psychic-spawn/), which led to me searching for the novel's title and finding the Goodreads entry.

Comment: What was that title again?

Comment: @LAK THE CHILDREN

Comment: @LAK not sure, but something with “children” in the title, iirc

Comment: So we should read this novel. For THE CHILDREN.

Comment: This synopsis also sounds extremely similar to Antony Horowitz's novel Stormbreaker in the Alex Rider series.

Comment: Somebody *really* didn't like Howard Hughes, huh?  He may have been a little eccentric, and maybe not the nicest guy in the world, but casting him as a serial murderer seems a bit extreme.  Especially since he'd only been dead 6 years when this was published...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Maybe they were conflating [a different Howard Hughes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_Sophie_Hook)?

Comment: Well, the book was published 6 years before that girl was even born, let alone murdered, so that would be some next-level prophesizing...

Comment: Oh, good point. :)

Comment: I think it was "The Bus that Couldn't Stop"...